# How to add an onClick event handler to a canvas shape in Elm?

Tags: elm

Is it possible to add an onClick event handler to `Graphics.Collage.square`?

I'd like to know the relative position of the click.

In Javascript, I could do something like [this](http://jsbin.com/zikaxoguvu/1/edit?html,css,js,output):

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
var canvasPosition = {
  x: canvas.offsetLeft,
  y: canvas.offsetTop
};

canvas.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
  console.log(event.x - canvasPosition.x, event.y - canvasPosition.y);
}, false);
```

Is that possible to do something similar in Elm?

Example would be appreciated.

Comment: I'm not sure, but I think if you need handlers like that, you should be using [elm-html](http://package.elm-lang.org/packages/evancz/elm-html/4.0.1) instead of the (somewhat dated) Collage

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Elm, using the Canvas rendering, you should use the `Mouse.clicks` signal and react to changes in the signal. Here's a runnable example of how that would work:

```
import Graphics.Element exposing (Element, show)
import Mouse

clicks : Signal (Int, Int)
clicks =
  Signal.sampleOn Mouse.clicks Mouse.position

main : Signal Element
main =
  Signal.map show clicks
```

In essence, `Mouse.clicks` are the actual "events" we are interested in, so whenever one happens, we "sample" the `Mouse.position` signal to get the click position.

`Signal.sampleOn` produces a signal that updates with the value of the second parameter signal (here, the mouse position) whenever there is a change in the first parameter signal (here, the mouse clicks).

Now, just to get the result showing, we are also mapping the position to the `show` function in `main`.

You can also paste this code to http://elm-lang.org/try, compile and try clicking the right-hand side to see it working.

Comment: I'd like to know where exactly in the canvas shape user clicked. Knowing where the shape is located on the screen, its dimension, and the position of the mouse click (`Mouse.position`), I could calculate whether the  shape was clicked or not, and if yes, where exactly. But, this could become not that trivial to calculate if the shape is not simple. I wonder if there is a more automated way to achieve this.

Comment: Yes, well you probably do know where the shape is. And if I'm not mistaken, the `Mouse.position` is by default relative to the Elm canvas. The only thing missing is the collision detection, for which you can use for example http://package.elm-lang.org/packages/bakkemo/elm-collision/1.0.0 .

Answer (score 0):

I implemented a [proof-of-concept backbuffer test](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/elm-discuss/Ee2_MfauicE/_635u_oJ4_UJ). It's pretty hacky but it might do the job.

If you don't like that, your only option is to find the mouse click location (which involves a very annoying conversion from the Mouse's top-left origin, y is down to Graphics.Collage's centered origin, y is up), and then do geometric collision detection. Which isn't too bad with circles and axis-aligned rectangles, but I get it, you want a general solution.

You can also consider using [elm-svg](http://package.elm-lang.org/packages/evancz/elm-svg/latest) which has typical DOM events like `mouseenter`, although I'm not sure how reliable the event dispatch is for e.g. convex shapes. Or you could abandon Elm entirely (sniff) and use D3.js with SVG.