# Elm: adding click events to SVG elements doesn't work – is this possible?

Tags: svg, mouseevent, elm

I have been attempting to add an `on "click"` event to an SVG element in Elm in order to determine the relative position of the mouse click within that element.

A code sample is given below that you can try running at http://elm-lang.org/try to show how click events on HTML elements seem to work as expected but not on SVG elements.

In the sample, `Html.on "click"` is used rather than `Html.onClick` to allow the position data to be decoded from the event as explained in [this discussion](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/elm-discuss/0d00KX0i3iU).

After reading the documentation and the source code, I would expect that when the `on "click"` event is added to an SVG element it would work in the same manner as adding the event to an HTML element. However when this is done, clicking the SVG element does not trigger the event and no message is sent to the update function.

In this example, clicking within the black SVG `rect` should trigger the update function and change the position of the white `rect` but the clicks are ignored. This can be confirmed by opening the console and noting that the `Debug.log` is not invoked. An HTML `div` is placed below with an identical click event and when a click is registered inside this `div`, the white `rect` changes position.

Is this intended behaviour in Elm and are there any workarounds?

A similar question has been asked on stackoverflow [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33382837/how-to-add-an-onclick-event-handler-to-a-canvas-shape-in-elm) but this is referring to canvas shapes which, as far as I'm aware, is a completely separate issue (I may be wrong though).

### Code sample:

```
import Html exposing (Html, div)
import Html.App as App
import Html.Attributes
import Html.Events exposing (on)
import Json.Decode as Json exposing (object2, int, at)
import Mouse exposing (Position)
import Svg exposing (svg, rect)
import Svg.Attributes exposing (..)

main =
  App.beginnerProgram
    { model = model
    , view = view
    , update = update
    }

type alias Model =
  Position

type Msg
  = ChangePosition Position

model : Model
model =
  Position 0 0

update : Msg -> Model -> Model
update msg _ =
  case Debug.log "msg" msg of
    ChangePosition position ->
      position

view : Model -> Html Msg
view model =
  div []
    [ svg
        [ width "400"
        , height "100"
        , viewBox "0 0 400 100"
        ]
        [ rect
            [ onClickLocation -- this should work but does nothing
            , width "400"
            , height "100"
            , x "0"
            , y "0"
            , fill "#000"
            , cursor "pointer"
            ]
            []
        , rect
            [ width "50"
            , height "50"
            , x (toString model.x)
            , y "20"
            , fill "#fff"
            ]
            []
        ]
    , div
        [ onClickLocation -- this works
        , Html.Attributes.style
            [ ( "background-color", "white" )
            , ( "border", "2px solid black" )
            , ( "width", "400px" )
            , ( "height", "100px" )
            , ( "position", "absolute" )
            , ( "left", "0px" )
            , ( "top", "150px" )
            , ( "color", "black" )
            , ( "cursor", "pointer" )
            ]
        ]
        [ div [] [ Html.text "Click in here to move x position of white svg square. Relative click coordinates shown below (y coordinate ignored)." ]
        , div [] [ Html.text (toString model) ]
        ]
    ]

onClickLocation : Html.Attribute Msg
onClickLocation =
  on "click"
    (Json.map
      ChangePosition
      (object2
        Position
        (object2 (-)
          (at [ "pageX" ] int)
          (at [ "target", "offsetLeft" ] int)
        )
        (object2 (-)
          (at [ "pageY" ] int)
          (at [ "target", "offsetTop" ] int)
        )
      )
    )
```

Comment: I think you should be using `Svg.Events` instead of `Html.Events`.

Comment: BTW, I do not find event.target.offsetLeft exist in the event handler.

Comment: Sorry I should have mentioned in the original question, using `Svg.Events.on` has exactly the same results as `Html.Events.on` when compiled normally. The reason I did not include this in the code sample is because for some reason it does not work at [http://elm-lang.org/try](http://elm-lang.org/try), giving the error `'Svg.Events' does not expose 'on'`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The reason Json decoder did not work is obvious because
none of `offsetLeft` nor `offsetTop` exist in the
event object.

It is somewhat confusing as those properties are available
for click event of Html DOM but not for SVG DOM.
(My suggestion of
implementing event decoders in Elm is to attach temporary
event handler in browser's debugger console and study the actual event object.  Elm's decoder silently fails and hard to know why the decoder
did not work.
)

Here, I implemented an alternate way how you can use `port` to get
parent position using javascript (without using any 
community libraries).

```elm
port module Main exposing (main)

import Html exposing (Html, div)
import Html.App as App
import Html.Attributes
import Html.Events exposing (on)
import Json.Decode as Json exposing (object2, object1, int, at)
import Mouse exposing (Position)
import Svg exposing (svg, rect)
import Svg.Attributes exposing (..)

main : Program Never
main =
  App.program
    { init = (initmodel, getParentPos ())
    , view = view
    , update = update
    , subscriptions = subscriptions
    }

type alias Model =
  { position : Position
  , parentPosition : Position
  }

type Msg
  = ChangePosition Position
  | UpdateParentPosition { top : Int, left : Int }

initmodel : Model
initmodel =
  { position = Position 0 0
  , parentPosition = Position 0 0
  }

update : Msg -> Model -> (Model, Cmd Msg)
update msg model =
  case Debug.log "msg" msg of
    ChangePosition position ->
      let
        relativepos = Position
          ( position.x - model.parentPosition.x )
          ( position.y - model.parentPosition.y )
      in ({ model | position = relativepos } , Cmd.none)
    UpdateParentPosition {top, left} ->
      ({ model | parentPosition = Position top left }, Cmd.none)

port getParentPos : () -> Cmd msg

subscriptions : Model -> Sub Msg
subscriptions model =
  parentPos UpdateParentPosition

port parentPos : ({ top : Int, left : Int } -> msg) -> Sub msg

view : Model -> Html Msg
view model =
  div []
    [ svg
        [ width "400"
        , height "100"
        , viewBox "0 0 400 100"
        , id "parent"
        ]
        [ rect
            [ onClickLocation -- this should work but does nothing
            , width "400"
            , height "100"
            , x "0"
            , y "0"
            , fill "#000"
            , cursor "pointer"
            ]
            []
        , rect
            [ width "50"
            , height "50"
            , x (toString model.position.x)
            , y (toString model.position.y)
            , fill "#fff"
            ]
            []
        ]
    , div
        [ onClickLocation -- this works
        , Html.Attributes.style
            [ ( "background-color", "white" )
            , ( "border", "2px solid black" )
            , ( "width", "400px" )
            , ( "height", "100px" )
            , ( "position", "absolute" )
            , ( "left", "0px" )
            , ( "top", "150px" )
            , ( "color", "black" )
            , ( "cursor", "pointer" )
            ]
        ]
        [ div [] [ Html.text "Click in here to move x position of white svg square. Relative click coordinates shown below (y coordinate ignored)." ]
        , div [] [ Html.text (toString model) ]
        ]
    ]

onClickLocation : Html.Attribute Msg
onClickLocation =
  on "click"
    (Json.map
      ChangePosition
      (object2
        Position
          (at [ "pageX" ] int)
          (at [ "pageY" ] int)
      )
    )
```

javascript:

```javascript
const app = Elm.Main.fullscreen();

app.ports.getParentPos.subscribe(() => {
  const e = document.querySelector('#parent');
  const rect = e.getBoundingClientRect();
  app.ports.parentPos.send({
    top: Math.round(rect.top),
    left: Math.round(rect.left)
  });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for this, would you mind elaborating on what you mean by having to use a port? Unfortunately this solution will not work in my use case because knowing the relative position of the click within the element is essential.

Comment: I updated my answer to demonstrate how port can be used.

Comment: Thanks again but my question was asked more with the intention of finding out why there is an inherent discrepancy between the use of the click event on an HTML element and an SVG one. If you take the HTML case, `offsetLeft` and `offsetTop` clearly do exist because you can place the HTML element anywhere on the page and the relative position is correctly determined.

Comment: What is your target browser?  I do not see them in firefox 49.0.2.  If you want to support multiple browsers, you do not want to rely on those browser specific features.

Comment: Any browser really. It's not a critical component but I just tested it in Safari 9.1.2 (11601.7.7), Chromium 53.0.2785.116 and Firefox 49.0.02. It works with all of them. "It" being if you move the HTML element to any position on the page with the sample I provided and click within it, you get the correct relative position value.

Comment: Yes, html and svg seem to have different API.  If you google it, there are some discussions (e.g. https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=552113).  I am afraid that I cannot give you any reasonable answer about why those properties are not given for svg dom api.  If that is what you are looking for, I suggest you to post separate question (which obviously has nothing to do with Elm, but it is about standardization of SVG.).

Comment: That's great, thank you for the link. I couldn't find this myself after hours of searching. The difficulty is if you don't know the answer it's hard to know what search terms to use. If you feel like updating your answer to explain that it is a result of different DOM APIs for HTML and SVG, I'll mark it as correct. But genuinely, thanks a lot for your help, this stumped me for far too many hours.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the fixed version of your example using the VirtualDom. I've upgraded it to elm v0.18 as well. 
Note just like the accepted answer this just gets the pageX/pageY position and not the relative position. I didn't expand on that.

The relevant changes start at the bottom starting from `onClickLocation`

```
import Html exposing (Html, div)
import Html.Attributes
import Html.Events exposing (on)
import Json.Decode as Json exposing (..)
import Svg exposing (svg, rect)
import Svg.Attributes exposing (..)
import VirtualDom

main =
  Html.beginnerProgram
    { model = model
    , view = view
    , update = update
    }

type alias Position =
    { x : Int
    , y : Int
    }

type alias Model =
  Position

type Msg
  = ChangePosition Position

model : Model
model =
  Position 0 0

update : Msg -> Model -> Model
update msg _ =
  case Debug.log "msg" msg of
    ChangePosition position ->
      position

view : Model -> Html Msg
view model =
  div []
    [ svg
        [ width "400"
        , height "100"
        , viewBox "0 0 400 100"
        ]
        [ rect
            [ onClickLocation -- this should work but does nothing
            , width "400"
            , height "100"
            , x "0"
            , y "0"
            , fill "#000"
            , cursor "pointer"
            ]
            []
        , rect
            [ width "50"
            , height "50"
            , x (toString model.x)
            , y "20"
            , fill "#fff"
            ]
            []
        ]
    , div
        [ onClickLocation -- this works
        , Html.Attributes.style
            [ ( "background-color", "white" )
            , ( "border", "2px solid black" )
            , ( "width", "400px" )
            , ( "height", "100px" )
            , ( "position", "absolute" )
            , ( "left", "0px" )
            , ( "top", "150px" )
            , ( "color", "black" )
            , ( "cursor", "pointer" )
            ]
        ]
        [ div [] [ Html.text "Click in here to move x position of white svg square. Relative click coordinates shown below (y coordinate ignored)." ]
        , div [] [ Html.text (toString model) ]
        ]
    ]

onClickLocation : Html.Attribute Msg
onClickLocation =
    mouseClick ChangePosition


offsetPosition : Json.Decoder Position
offsetPosition =
    Json.map2 Position (field "pageX" Json.int) (field "pageY" Json.int)


mouseEvent : String -> (Position -> msg) -> VirtualDom.Property msg
mouseEvent event messager =
    let
        options =
            { preventDefault = True, stopPropagation = True }
    in
        VirtualDom.onWithOptions event options (Json.map messager offsetPosition)


mouseClick : (Position -> msg) -> VirtualDom.Property msg
mouseClick =
    mouseEvent "click"
```