# Elm handle mousemove / write event handler

Tags: svg, mousemove, elm

I'm trying to implement SVG drawing app.

I was using http://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm-lang/mouse/1.0.1/Mouse, but it generates subscriptions which provides position relative to whole document, not relative to my SVG element.

So, I decided to switch to using `onmousemove`.

Here is fragment of my program:

```
type MouseState = Up | Down

type alias Model = {
    mousePosition: Position,
    mouseState: MouseState,
    path: List Position
}

type Msg = MouseMove Position
    | MouseUp Position
    | MouseDown Position
    | Noop

update: Msg -> Model -> (Model, Cmd Msg)
update msg model =
    case msg of 
        MouseMove position -> ({model |
            mousePosition = position,
            path = position :: model.path
        }, Cmd.none)
        MouseUp position -> ({model | mouseState = Up}, Cmd.none)
        MouseDown position -> ({model | mouseState = Down}, Cmd.none)
        _ -> (model, Cmd.none)

subscriptions: Model -> Sub Msg
subscriptions model =
    Sub.batch [
        -- Mouse.moves MouseMove, -- remove this
        Mouse.ups MouseUp,
        Mouse.downs MouseDown
    ]

view: Model -> Html Msg
view model =
    div [] [
        div [] [
            Html.text (
                (toString model.mouseState)
                ++ ", " ++
                (toString model.mousePosition.x)
                ++ ", " ++
                (toString model.mousePosition.y)
            )],
        svg [ width "1200", height "1200", viewBox "0 0 1200 1200", on "mousemove" MouseMove] (
            List.map drawPoint model.path
        )
    ]
```

But compiling this of course gives me error:

```
Function `on` is expecting the 2nd argument to be:

    Json.Decode.Decoder a

But it is:

    Position -> Msg

Hint: I always figure out the type of arguments from left to right. If an
argument is acceptable when I check it, I assume it is "correct" in subsequent
checks. So the problem may actually be in how previous arguments interact with
the 2nd.
```

Which brings up two questions: how to write some decoder which transforms event JSON to string, to see what is inside, and how then to write decoder which fetches coordinates from that event?

Comment: Just a possible direction which you may want to look into: http://stackoverflow.com/a/40334086/1238847

Answer (score 1):

You need a [`Decoder`](http://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm-lang/core/5.0.0/Json-Decode#Decoder) to that msg. Your message is `MouseMove`, a function from `Position -> Msg`. What you need is something whose signature is `Decoder Msg`. The `on` takes the event in so we'll need to use a decoder to get the proper information off of that. I'm not really sure which Xs and Ys you need from JavaScript's `MouseEvent`, but we'll use `layerX` and `layerY` for this example (and you can change it to the right one). We can solve this with [applicatives](https://toast.al/posts/2016-08-12-elm-applicatives-and-json-decoders.html).

```
import Json.Decode as Decode exposing (Decoder)
import Json.Decode.Extra as Decode exposing ((|:))


mouseMoveDecoder : Decoder Msg
mouseMoveDecoder =
    Decode.succeed MouseMove
        |: (Decode.succeed Position
            |: (Decode.field "layerX" Decode.int)
            |: (Decode.field "layerY" Decode.int)
        )
```

and

```
svg [ on "mousemove" mouseMoveDecoder ] [ ... ]
```

Comment: Alas, there are no versions of circuithub/elm-json-extra that work with Elm 0.17.1. :( I guess I need to learn more of this language just to understand your answer. :)

Comment: [This version does](http://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm-community/json-extra/1.1.0)

Comment: Oops, looks like I forgot to do `npm update -g elm`. When learning new technology, probably better to make sure you are learning latest version.